Cannot autowire open feign client
I have the following open feign client:
package com.example.feignclientch11.clients;

import com.example.feignclientch11.entities.Payment;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

@FeignClient(name = "payments",
            url = "${name.service.url}")
public interface PaymentsProxy {

    @PostMapping("/payment")
    Payment createPayment(@RequestHeader String requestId, @RequestBody Payment payment);
}

and the configuration class to enable open feign clients:
package com.example.feignclientch11;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.example.feignclientch11.clients")
public class ProjectConfig {

}



and then I try to autowire it in the controller:
@RestController
public class PaymentsController {

    private final PaymentsProxy paymentsProxy;

    public PaymentsController(PaymentsProxy paymentsProxy) {
        this.paymentsProxy = paymentsProxy;
    }

    @GetMapping("/payment")
    public Payment createPayment(@RequestBody Payment payment) {
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return paymentsProxy.createPayment(requestId, payment);
    }
}


and this is the main class:
package com.example.feignclientch11;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Feignclientch11Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Feignclientch11Application.class, args);
    }

}


but intellij complains Could not autowire. No beans of 'PaymentsProxy' type found.  that it is not able to autowire the bean.
This is the runtime log:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)

2024-07-27T18:23:34.701+03:00  INFO 7074 --- [feignclientch11] [  restartedMain] c.e.f.Feignclientch11Application         : Starting Feignclientch11Application using Java 18.0.2 with PID 7074 (/Users/cristiandanila/Desktop/pers-workspace/snippets/book-snippets/spring-start-here/ch11/feignclientch11/target/classes started by cristiandanila in /Users/cristiandanila/Desktop/pers-workspace/snippets/book-snippets/spring-start-here/ch11/feignclientch11)
2024-07-27T18:23:34.703+03:00  INFO 7074 --- [feignclientch11] [  restartedMain] c.e.f.Feignclientch11Application         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-27T18:23:34.740+03:00  INFO 7074 --- [feignclientch11] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-07-27T18:23:35.114+03:00  INFO 7074 --- [feignclientch11] [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=7b4988c0-43d4-309b-bebe-377053bec13d
2024-07-27T18:23:35.249+03:00  INFO 7074 --- [feignclientch11] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-07-27T18:23:35.397+03:00  INFO 7074 --- [feignclientch11] [  restartedMain] c.e.f.Feignclientch11Application         : Started Feignclientch11Application in 0.958 seconds (process running for 6.437)

Process finished with exit code 0

This is the pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>feignclientch11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>feignclientch11</name>
    <description>feignclientch11</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Not sure why it behaves like this.

please show your Feignclientch11Application class and add/show package of PaymentsProxy class

@JAsgarov Edited

seems correct so far, please show your pom.xml

everything seems correct, the only thing I can think of is that perhaps the ProjectConfig is in some weird package that doesn't get picked up? What is it's package? Or just try defining @EnableFeignClients without any base packages right over Feignclientch11Application

package com.example.feignclientch11; is the package

everything you have provided so far is absolutely ok - could it be that it is simply an intellij error (for whatev reason) and the application acutally works fine? Try debugging it and see if the autowired value is indeed null

what is your "name.service.url"? is it available in your configs? do you have discovery service online?

It is working now after removing spring-dev-tools and adding spring-starter-web dependencies to pom.xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>feignclientch11</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>feignclientch11</name>
    <description>feignclientch11</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>202thank you! I3.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<!--    <dependencyManagement>-->
<!--        <dependencies>-->
<!--            <dependency>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>-->
<!--                <type>pom</type>-->
<!--                <scope>import</scope>-->
<!--            </dependency>-->
<!--        </dependencies>-->
<!--    </dependencyManagement>-->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



It seems like your configuration class ProjectConfig  is not picked up by spring .
You can fix this by removing the ProjectConfig class  and adding the annotation @EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.example.feignclientch11.clients") to your main class.

Tried this and it didn't work

Could you please make sure that the bean is not created ! Because it might be IDE error , just put some break points or add logging level debug springframework
